# Are questions along the lines of "Is the site example.com a scam?" on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Someone has recently shared with me a link to what strongly smells like a scam site (it's a pyramid-link-share scheme type thing).

I've googled the site so I can provide hard evidence to the sharer that they should avoid it, but it seems to be very new and there's little to no information about it that I can find.

Is it on-topic to ask if that specific site is a scam?

Comment: xyz.com is a commercial site (which may or may not be a scam: I make no comment). If you want a placeholder example domain, may I suggest using http://example.com?

Comment: Good point; I've amended the question.

Comment: This *might* be one topic at skeptics. I've seen one [similar question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/37941) there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it's not on topic. We do not do security reviews of products, services, or sites.

Comment: What about scam schemes ? I think you could always ask how a certain sites scam works or could theoretically work. Or what about ways to verify that a site is real ? Eg. if someone sets up faebook.com and tries to phish people, is the question how to determine if the site belongs to facebook.com on topic ?

Comment: "How scams work" is off-topic. How to validate a website actually has answered questions here, so would be closed as a dupe. I'm open to some form of the question to be on-topic, but I can't think of one at the moment.